# display a screenshot of a page within a given set of coordinates on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, interact.js

I am dynamically selecting an image and placing it over another image, which is inside a parent container say a div or canvas. A save button saves the screenshot of canvas/element(the parent container) to another div/canvas but it is not capturing the dynamically added image. I have tried it without canvas as well.
Here is how I tried to save it onto a new canvas

```
   $("#Savebtn").click(function(){

        var c = document.getElementById('parent');
    var t = c.getContext('2d');
    window.open('', document.getElementById('parent').toDataURL());

    });
```

For some reason I could not reference external scripts, so here is my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWwJYP#anon-login

Is there a way with which I could take a screenshot of the screen within the particular coordinates and display it in another container(Detaching the dom elements will not work as they are not placed together and nor will it capture the location of dynamically placed image).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should go for some library like html2canvas

Comment: I have tried html2js  `$("#Savebtn").click(function(){
$('body').html2canvas();

var queue = html2canvas.Parse();

var canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue,{elements:{length:1}});

var img = canvas.toDataURL();

window.open(img);

});`
   But it gave me `$(...).html2canvas is not a function` error

Comment: Can you include the full code including jQuery in your question

Comment: I tried html2js as well but I think it can't capture images , here is a fiddle to show the same
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/699j050r/360/

and here was my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWwJYP#anon-login